# Importing Google I/O source? hg clone

Tags: java, android, svn, mercurial

Hey im trying to grab the google I/O source code so  i can learn from it but I cant seem to do it. I installed TortoiseHG but it keeps erroring out when i try to clone it. Can someone upload it somewhere or tell me the correct way to copy the source to my hdd using tortoisehg?

```
http://code.google.com/p/iosched/
```

Comment: hg clone https://iosched.googlecode.com/hg/ iosched

     .Im on windows 7 btw.

Answer (score 2):

The url you have is the project homepage, not the repository url. Try -

```
hg clone https://iosched.googlecode.com/hg/ <your local directory>
```

Comment: Yes I know that is waht i was putting in, ill try again.

Comment: Keep getting this error in tortoiseHG

{{{
#!python
** Mercurial version (1.8.3).  TortoiseHg version (2.0.4)
** Command: --nofork clone
** CWD: C:\rapid
** Extensions loaded: fixfrozenexts
** Python version: 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Windows version: (6, 1, 7600, 2, '')
** Processor architecture: x64
** Qt-4.7.1 PyQt-4.8.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\clone.pyo", line 313, in clone
  File "genericpath.pyo", line 18, in exists
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

}}}

Comment: Ok so i was able to download the file, now I dont see a project file so how do i go about compiling this? Do i have to manually bring in each file/folder into a new project?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/issues/detail?id=5#c6 should be useful. If the answer has helped you with your original question, consider accepting it as the correct answer. (FYI if you plan to be active in SO community, largely, SO community does not encourage asking separate, follow up questions in comments. You should ideally ask a separate question (link to this if necessary) for the build/compile problem.)